# Leaflet: Raster Grid on map with different colors

Tags: leaflet, maps

I am new to Leaflet and I want to create a raster and add it to my map. The raster is inside inside a polygon, which means I have many polygons (squares). Currently, I am adding just squares, but this makes everything very slow. It should look like this:

[image: My current solution with squares].

I also want to display a popup when hovering over a square with some information related to the square.

What I just tried:

- I tried to use the GridLayer class for this but it seems I can mask it so that it just shows only specific squares.
- There a various plugins but I do not really understand what they are doing

Has anyone an idea how this can be implemented?

Thank you

Comment: Use a `L.ImageOverlay`, set its `interactive` option to `true`, and use an event handler on its `mouseover` (or `pointerover`) event. Use the event's `offsetX`/`offsetY` properties to calculate the pixel coordinates of the raster that should be queried to get the pixel value. Get yourself acquainted with mouse/pointer events (do read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and canvas manipulation (read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas ). Read the code of `L.DomEvent.getMousePosition`, too.

Comment: So you suggest to use one image overlay and change the image color depending on the color I need by using mouse event? Or one Image layer for each point?

Comment: One image, one pixel per square. Prepare the image in advance.